# How to enter a limit order above or below last entre price in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy that places limit orders on the same bar. Sometimes it places orders at the exact same price as a previous order. How can I prevent this?

Something like this:

`lastEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1)`

`limitOrder != lastEntryPrice`

Comment: You should copy/paste here the whole code, otherwise it's impossible to help

Comment: If order is not fulfilled but pending, then your'e getting `lastEntryPrice` which is the price of the last fulfilled order (may be from previous bar). Additionally you can check whether strategy.opentrades value is increased. And yes, it is just vanga guessing, please provide full code

Comment: Sorry, I do not have code. I am looking for a suggestion on how to do it.